# custom_plugin wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

estoy desarollando un plugin en Wordpress para crear y personalizar custom_post_type, ya tengo añadido el metabox. Pero en el cuadro de texto donde se escribiría el texto que fuera del post, me aparece el siguiente warning. Ya he mirado esa línea de código y no consigo ver el error.

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-content/plugins/pluginPrueba.php on line 66 Call Stack: 0.0060 239120 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-admin/post-new.php:0 0.3596 9932952 2. include('/home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php') /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-admin/post-new.php:79 0.3639 9954696 3. register_and_do_post_meta_boxes(???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php:228 0.3680 9972184 4. do_action(???, ???, ???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-admin/includes/meta-boxes.php:1416 0.3680 9972944 5. WP_Hook->do_action(???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/plugin.php:453 0.3680 9973040 6. WP_Hook->apply_filters(???, ???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:310 0.3680 9974544 7. call_user_func_array:{/home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288}(???, ???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288 0.3680 9974608 8. add_metabox(???) /home/ubuntu/workspace/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php:288
```

la línea que supuestamente devuelve el error es un foreach que recorrer el array de campos

```
function measure_add_meta_box() {

    $s = array('made_to_measure');
    // Para cada pantalla de edición del custom post type...
    foreach ( $s as $screen ) {
        /* El formato es add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $screen, $context, $priority, $callback_args ); 
          $id - es el ID html del metabox
          $title - el nombre que aparecerá al lado del campo
          $callback - es la función que dará uso a nuestro metabox, en ella definimos los campos que habrá en el metabox
          $screen - es donde queremos que se muestre el metabox, en nuestro caso deberá ser cada página que lo contenga
          $context - dentro de la entrada donde queremos que se muestre, si lo ponemos a normal le estamos diciendo que lo muestre justo debajo del editor de texto del campo descripción que viene por defecto en todas las entradas
          $priority - le dice a Wordpress dónde cargar el metabox en el contenido. Por defecto dejaremos a default
          $callback_args - consultar el codex 
        */
        add_meta_box( 'measure_sectionid', 'measure Details', 'made_to_measure_callback', $screen, 'normal' );
     }
```

}

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'measure_add_meta_box' );
```

gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `66` del archivo `pluginPrueba.php`?

Comment: @A.Cedano lo primero gracias por responder. Como digo en mi pregunta. El error lo devuelve el foreach que recorre el array   // Para cada pantalla de edición del custom post type...
    foreach ( $s as $screen ) {

Comment: Lo que quería saber es si la línea 66 es donde empieza el `foreach` o es otra línea.

Comment: @A.Cedano esta es la línea 66, perdone; $s = array('made_to_measure');

Comment: Es raro que en esa línea de un *`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`* ¿?  ¿O acaso hay más código que llama a ese código?

Comment: Hay una llamada a esta función, y luego código php para un custom post type